# Django 1.3 passing parameters to filter of class-based generic list view in url.py

Tags: regex, django, url, view, tags

Here's my code in url.py:

```
(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/$',
    ListView.as_view(
        model=List,
        context_object_name='some_list',
        queryset=List.objects.filter(tag__name__in=[tag_name]),
        template_name='some_list.html'))
```

I'd like to pass `(?P<tag>\w+)` to "`tag_name`" filter, but I don't know how to do it.

Also how can I pass multiple tags? Like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/tag/tag1+tag2+tag3
```

url.py should get "`tag1+tag2+tag3`", split it into "`tag1`", "`tag2`" and "`tag3`", and then put them in "`tag__name__in`":

```
queryset=List.objects.filter(tag__name__in=[tag1, tag2, tag3])
```

Basically I'm confused by the class-based generic view. Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can overwrite the view's `get_queryset` method and construct a queryset with your results, eg.

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class MyList(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        tag_list = self.kwargs['tags'].split('+')
        return List.objects.filter(tag__name__in=tag_list)

# urls.py
...
url(r'tag/(?<tags>[\w\+]+)/', MyList.as_view())
```